# psql command problem with // (double-slash)

Tags: postgresql, azure, psql

```
/COPY MondayLotto FROM 'https://thelottoproject.blob.core.windows.net/data/MondayLotto.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

The command returns these error messages

(In Azure Cloud Shell terminal)

> https:/thelottoproject.blob.core.windows.net/data/MondayLotto.csv: No such file or directory

(In SQL Shell (psql) on Windows10)

> https:/thelottoproject.blob.core.windows.net/data/MondayLotto.csv: Invalid argument

I guess the `//` caused the error because the error message shows only `/` after https:

- PostgreSQL server in Azure
- The CSV file in Azure blob storage is accessible.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) it has to be `\copy` not `/copy` but you can't have a URL as the source unless Postgres on Azure is different from "stock" Postgres

Answer (score 0):

psql special commands starting by `\` so the syntax should be

```
\copy MondayLotto FROM ...
```

Probably there will be second issue too. I don't know how the table `MondayLotto` was created. This looks like case sensitive identifier, and if it is really case sensitive identifier, then it should be used inside parentheses like `"MondayLotto"`.

Answer (score 0):

To load data from a web site, you could run something like

```sh
wget -O - https://thelottoproject.blob.core.windows.net/data/MondayLotto.csv | psql -c "COPY mondaylotto FROM STDIN (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER)"
```

Comment: I tried explicitly copy and paste your code and it returned error. So I did more googling and found something I think it what you meant---> \copy words FROM program 'wget -q -O - https://www.depesz.com/various/words.csv'  from https://www.depesz.com/2013/02/28/waiting-for-9-3-add-support-for-piping-copy-tofrom-an-external-program/

However it still not working for me either on Azure or psql shell. They just wouldn't recognized "wget" command

Comment: You need to be superuser or member of `pg_execute_server_program` to use `COPY FROM PROGRAM`. My code should work without these high privileges. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Maybe there is no `wget` installed on your client machine?